# How I can parse time in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, time

I have time (string) in this format: `01:01:01:01` (hours/minutes/seconds/milliseconds).

And I need to parse this time to milliseconds (number), how I can do this?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: Isn't this just a matter of multiplication?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code ........

```js
var string = "01:01:01:01";
var string_array = string.split(":");
var hours = string_array[0];
var mins = string_array[1];
var seconds = string_array[2];
var miliseconds = string_array[3];

var total_miliseconds = (hours*60*60*1000) + (mins*60*1000) + (seconds*1000) + (miliseconds);

console.log ("Total Miliseconds: " + total_miliseconds);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```js
function toMilisecond(time) {
  [hours, mins, seconds, miliseconds] = time.split(":");
  return hours * 3600000 + mins * 60000 + seconds * 1000 + Number(miliseconds);
}

console.log(toMilisecond("01:01:01:01"));
```

Comment: `time.split(":").map(Number)` otherwise you get strings. That's not an issue with multiplication, as it converts operands to numbers implicitly, however `+ miliseconds` will then implicitly convert to string and concatenate.

Comment: @VLAZ That was very stupid of me . Thank You!... I have updated it.